# pandas groupby boxplot red diagonal line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm plotting a box plot with

```
>>> score.head()
       Score  Wafer_Slot
0 -10.710504          14
1   1.444185          23
2  -5.727797          14
3   8.029544          21
4  -1.569401          24

gscore = score.groupby('Wafer_Slot')
xticks = []
for i in range(25):
    xticks.append(str(i+1))
    xticks.append(' ')

gscore.boxplot(subplots=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)
plt.ylabel('Anomaly Score', size=20)
plt.xlabel('Wafer Slot', size=20)
plt.show()
```

The plot is fine but there is a dashed red diagonal line. What is this line? How can I remove it?

Obtained figure:

[image]

EDIT:
This is a reproducible example:

```
score = pd.DataFrame()
score['Score'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
score['Wafer_Slot'] = np.random.choice(range(25), 1000)

gscore = score.groupby('Wafer_Slot')
xticks = []
for i in range(25):
    xticks.append(str(i+1))
    xticks.append(' ')

gscore.boxplot(column=0, subplots=False)
ax = plt.gca()
#ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)
plt.ylabel('Anomaly Score', size=20)
plt.xlabel('Wafer Slot', size=20)
#plt.savefig(plot_path + 'ocsvm_box_plot_by_wafer_slot.pdf')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't get a diagonal red line if I run your code, can you show us a figure which shows the problem?

Comment: @Bart I added a figure

Comment: I removed my answer since it was nonsense...

Comment: I solved anyway. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved. It was enough to use a different variable as grouping index:

```
score['Score'] = svm_score
ws = desc.Wafer_Slot[test_index].tolist()

gscore = score.groupby(ws)
xticks = []
for i in range(25):
    xticks.append(str(i+1))
    #xticks.append(' ')

gscore.boxplot(subplots=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)
plt.ylabel('Anomaly Score', size=20)
plt.xlabel('Wafer Slot', size=20)
#plt.savefig(plot_path + 'ocsvm_box_plot_by_wafer_slot.pdf')

plt.show()
```